# Name of specific concatenation operation in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

Given a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$, with coefficients $a_{ij}$. I can construct a vector $x\in\mathbb R^{nm}$ where $x_{k} = x_{(i-1)n+j}=a_{ij}$, which would be equivalent to creating a large column vector which is the concatenation of all columns of $A$.

Is there a specific name for this operation? e.g., numpy has this as a built-in function  called 'ravel', but if I search for this I only get results for numpy, arguing that this is not a common name for this operation.

Comment: If it is crystal clear what that simple operation does why does it have to have a common name? Possible names are vectorisation or serialisation.

Comment: @KurtG. Just that it is clear does not mean that the operation has no name. The kronecker product can be explained as concise as the vectorization I describe, yet it has a name of its own. Similar arguments could be made that the transpose needs no specific name, though it has.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) satisfy you?